# does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import

Tags: django

Подскажите пожалуйста где здесь циклический импорт?

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to have any pat.urls' from 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\WORK-PROJECTS\python-learn\django-booked by a circular import.-mele-social_net\bookmarksprjct\images\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

forms.py

```
from urllib import request
from django import forms
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.utils.text import slugify
from .models import Image

class ImageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Image
       fields = ('title', 'url', 'description')
       widgets = {
            'url': forms.HiddenInput,
        }


def clean_url(self):
    url = self.cleaned_data['url']
    valid_extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg']
    extension = url.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
    if extension not in valid_extensions:
        raise forms.ValidationError('The given URL does not ' \
                                    'match valid image extensions.')
    return url

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
    image = super(ImageCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
    image_url = self.cleaned_data['url']
    image_name = '{}.{}'.format(slugify(image.title),
                              image_url.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower())

    # download image from the given URL
    response = request.urlopen(image_url)
    image.image.save(image_name,
                     ContentFile(response.read()),
                     save=False)
    if commit:
        image.save()
    return image
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'images'

url_patterns = [
  path('create/', views.image_create, name='create'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.text import slugify



class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             related_name='images_created', 
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                        related_name='images_liked',
                                        blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import ImageCreateForm

@login_required
def image_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            new_item = form.save(commit=False)
            new_item.user = request.user
            new_item.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Image addded successfully')
            return redirect(new_item.get_absolut_url())
    else:
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.GET)

    return render(request, 'images/image/create.html',
                  {'section': 'images', 'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),    
    path('images/', include('images.urls', namespace='images')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: А у вас случаноне опечатка ? `return redirect(new_item.get_absolut_url())`